# interaction terms to assess effect of a series of variable on the relationship between an independent variable and outcome variable

Tags: logistic, lme4-nlme, interaction

Let's say that I have an independent variable x1 which I'd like to explore its association with Y (a binary outcome variable). Furthermore I'd like to explore how x1 associated with Y when x2 interacting with them, x1 associated with Y when x3, .... when x10 is interacting with them.

I build the following model in R:
model <- glmer(Y ~ x1 * x2 + x1 * x3 + .... x1 * x10, family=binomial)

Is this a valid way to explore that task, and if not, any suggestions?